# No name 'QWebEnginePage' in module 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7, PyQt 5.12, VSCode "
**from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage** "Importing this line does not throw any error but I am getting a warning line "No name 'QWebEnginePage' in module 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'" . Can anyone explain me the reason for this warning?

I already have PyQtWebEngine installed and Its not an error message. I am able to run code successfully. I just wanted to know why a warning message is coming.

Comment: It is probably a bug of your IDE.

Comment: Who is generating the warning? If it's Pylint then it's been known to specifically have issues with `PyQt5`.